# SonarQube version <-> SonarJava version <-> Custom Plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-plugin

I'm trying to implement a custom SonarQube plugin which also works fine on my dev machine in Eclipse, but as soon as I deploy it to our SonarQube instance it crashes during runtime with a ClassNotFoundException. The class which it can't find during runtime is `ExpressionsHelper`, which (as far as I understand it) should be in the `sonar-java-plugin-***.jar`.

Our SonarQube instance is running version 6.1, the SonarJava plugin is installed in version 4.15.0.12310.

Now to which version(s) should I set which property in my pom.xml so that the configuration on my dev machine matches the available libraries on the SonarQube instances? I've tried setting them to sonar.version=6.1, java.plugin.version=4.15.0.12310 but then I still got the ClassNotFoundException during the scan.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the API you're using from SonarJava is public?

Comment: Yeah I believe so, but if you know any other way of getting the `String` content of a `Tree` from `ImportTree.qualifiedIdentifier()` I would gladly take that :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the class is not part of  package starting with :  `org.sonar.plugins.java.api` it won't be found at runtime.

`org.sonar.java.checks.helpers.ExpressionHelper` is not part of this package and so won't be found at runtime, hence the exception you encounter.

Comment: Okay - how would I extract the content of a ImportTree.qualifiedIdentifier() ideally then? Do I really have to reimplement the tree traversal? Is there nothing in the API for that?

Comment: As of today you would have to copy paste what is the ExpressionHelper, indeed, we don't provide such utilitities as API.